# Changing Undesired Type Inference In Haskell

Tags: haskell

My matrix multiplication implementation is:

```
mtrxMult :: (Num a) => [[a]] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mtrxMult [[]] _ _ = []
mtrxMult xs [] vec = 0 : mtrxMult xs vec vec
mtrxMult (x:xs) (v:vs) vec = head x * v + mtrxMult (tail x : xs) vs vec
```

The idea is that the function call `mtrxMult [[0,1],[1,0]] [2,3] [2,3]` will expand to `0 * 2 + 1 * 3 : 2 * 1 + 3 * 0 : []` which will evaluate to `[3,2]`. The compiler, however, expects x to be a list of lists rather than a list whose head is a number. What about Haskell's type inference system gives it that expectation and how would I alter the code for a coherent implementation of matrix multiplication?

Comment: Haven't finished looking through, but are you sure you want your base case to be `[[]]` (exactly one empty list inside of a list)?

Comment: I'm too tired to fix the algorthmic issues, but the type problems comes from using `+` on line 4 instead of `:`

Answer (score 1):

The compile time errors would be easy to fix, but I think you might have a larger issue here....

The signature of the expression is wrong.  I think you are trying to multiply an NxM matrix by a vector of length N, ie-

```
| a b |   | x |   | ax + by |
| c d | X | y | = | cx + dy |
| e f |           | ex + fy |
```

If I am correct, the signature of the function should be

```
mtrxMult::Num a=>[[a]]->[a]->[a]
```

and an implementation would be

```
dotMult::Num a=>[a]->[a]->a
dotMult x y | length x == length y = sum $ zipWith (*) x y
dotMult x y = error "Vectors should be of same length in call to dotMult"

mtrxMult::Num a=>[[a]]->[a]->[a]
mtrxMult m x | length x == length m = map (dotMult x) y
mtrxMult _ _ = error "Matrix width must be vector length"
```

(The runtime length checks bother me....  You could probably craft something that moves some of the typechecking to compile time by defining "data Matrix = Matrix [Vector]", but I just kept with the arrays here).